# Linearization of Nonlinear System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I am trying to linearize the following nonlinear system to determine the type of equilibrium point present. The system is

$x'=a-x-(4xy/(1+x^2))$

$y'=bx(1-(y/(1+x^2)))$

Do I do this by creating the jacobian, evaluating at the c.p., and solving for the eigenvalues?  With the two parameters a,b things get really messy when I try to solve for the eigenvalues. I thought there was a simpler way by simply ignoring the nonlinear terms...

Comment: You should use Latex/Mathjax to format your question so it is easier to understand.

Comment: To user75514:  I edited your post by putting "$" signs around the equations so they would be rendered as Latex.  Hope this is OK.

Comment: @user75514: Is the system written correctly?

Comment: @Amzoti:  Well, now that I look *carefully* at it, I think you are probably correct.  As I wrote, I stuck in the "$" signs and nothing else.  Someone should probably fix it.  user75514 hasn't been around since he/she posted, judging by the user profile.

Comment: @Amzoti:  OK, I altered it to read with $x^2$ instead of $x2$.

Comment: @Amzoti: I certainly don't feel *threatened*! ;-)

Comment: @Amzoti:  For all you know, *I* am trick-or-treating; for all I know, *you* are!  Happy Hallowe'en to one and all! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a differential equation of the form
$$q' = f(q)$$
where $f$ is some nonlinear function. I assume you are starting from some known equilibrium point $q_0$ where $f(q_0) = 0$. Now suppose you are a small displacement $q(t) = q_0 + \delta q(t)$ away from $q_0$. Plugging in you get
$$\delta q' = f(q_0 + \delta q).$$

Apply Taylor's theorem on the right-hand side to get
$$\delta q' = f(q_0) + \nabla f \cdot \delta q + O(\delta q^2).$$
Assuming small displacements, and that the Taylor coefficients of $f$ decay sufficiently quickly, etc. we can ignore the higher-order terms, to get the approximate, linearized ODE
$$\delta q' = 0 + \nabla f \cdot \delta q.$$

Solve this in the usual way, i.e. find the eigenvectors $v_i$ of $\nabla f$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, and notice these give you solutions of the form
$$\delta q = Ae^{\lambda_i t}v_i.$$

Comment: When you are dealing with a system of differential equations, this amount to  taking the Jacobian of the system, evaluating at the critical point, and then solving for the eigenvalues and vectors.  I guess things just get really messy because of the two parameters present...